# Fixing broken umlauts from database in ruby script

Tags: mysql, ruby, character-encoding

I'm working on a ruby script (using sequel) to transfer data from an old database to a new one. Because of an encoding problem with the old database I got values like "MÃ¼nchen" instead of "München".

```rb
DB = Sequel.mysql2 'db_name', user: 'name', password: '***', host: '127.0.0.1' # , encoding:  Encoding::CP1252.name) # doesn't work
city = DB[:users].first['city'] # => "MÃ¼nchen"
city.encoding # => #<Encoding:UTF-8>
city.encode(Encoding::UTF_8, Encoding::CP1252) # => "MÃƒÂ¼nchen"
```

The old db's encoding is set to CP1252, the new one is utf-8.

I tried to `#gsub` the broken umlauts, but that doesn't work:

```rb
umlauts = {
 'Ã¤' => 'ä',
 'Ã¶' => 'ö',
 'Ã¼' => 'ü',
 'ÃŸ' => 'ß'
}

city.gsub(/[#{umlauts.keys.join}]/, umlauts) # => "Mnchen"
```

I'm completely clueless how to correctly work with encoding, do you know how I can get 'München'?

Comment: What was it that didn't work about your gsub? mine works fine:  `string = "MÃ¼nchen";string.gsub("Ã¼", "ü");=> "München"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the way I used `#gsub` has been wrong (thanks Mike H-R!), this works:

```rb
umlauts = {
  'Ã¤' => 'ä',
  'Ã¶' => 'ö',
  'Ã¼' => 'ü',
  'ÃŸ' => 'ß'
}

city.gsub(/#{umlauts.keys.join("|")}/, umlauts)' # => "München"
```